# Area of a circle using integral...

Tags: integration, geometry, definite-integrals

How can I calculate area of a circle using integral. Please explain in depth.

Comment: Have you tried google'ing [calculate area of a circle using integral](https://www.google.com/#q=calculate+area+of+a+circle+using+integral)? The first two links (and probably the next 100 as well) explain it in detail.

Comment: Just after posting a question I realised that googling area of a circle using integral will give me explanation, but not surface area of a circle using integral... I'm not a native speaker so I'm having difficulties with math terms. That's why I asked this question, sry...

Comment: No apology necessary.

Comment: What do you mean with "surface area of a circle"? Perhaps "surface of a sphere"?

Comment: That's what was confusing me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Cavalieri's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle) for calculate the area of a circle. The principle says, that you can find the area/volume of a figure by using the integral "over" the cross-sections.

$$\lambda^n(A)= \int \lambda^{n-1}(C) \; dc$$

Suppose $M=(0,0)$ is the center of your circle $C$. Let $r$ be the radius.

Then you'll get the following drawing:

[image]

By using Pythagoas theorem, you can express $AC$ in dependence of $c$ (you heights).

Lets say $AC=a$, then $r^2=c^2+a^2 \Leftrightarrow a=\sqrt{r^2-c^2}=\lambda(C)$. Put it into

\begin{eqnarray*}
\lambda^2(C)&=& \int_{-r}^r \lambda(C) \; dc\\
&=& \int_{-r}^r \sqrt{r^2-c^2} \; dc\\
&=&\left[ \frac 1 2 (c \sqrt{r^2-c^2}+r^2 \tan^{-1}(\frac{c}{\sqrt{r^2-c^2}})\right]_{-r}^r
&=&\pi r^2
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I think $\lambda(C) = 2*\sqrt(r^2-c^2)$ is the length of a cross-section.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you a hint:

$$A = \int _0^R \! \! \! \int _0^{2\pi }r \, d\theta \, dr,$$

what do $r$, $\theta$, $r d\theta dr$, stand for?

Cheers!